# hibernate main method call

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm very new to Hibernate and just wanted to query the initial basics.

I've created my Hibernate bean as such...

```
package com.behaviour.chapter1;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class User {

    private int userId;
    private String firstName;

    @Id
    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
}
```

I've configured my hibernate.cfg.xml and db connection there.  My question is simply, how do I actually call this from a main method and use it in Hibernate3.6.6?  I was following a tutorial online but it was for Hibernate3.2 and it seems to be a bit different.  If anyone could show me just a really simple main method calling this bean, creating a new user (that would create a user in this table) it would be greatly appreciated.  Also - if anyone has any good Hibernate tutorial links that would be great :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this, it is a matter of design choice, a basic way to achieve this will be to create the session factory from `hibernate.cfg.xml` file. Make sure the file can be located at your classpath.

**And using the class below, create a Session Factory object which is then used to open up new Session's**

```
  public class HibernateUtil 
  {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

     static 
     {
      try 
        {
         // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
         sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
         } 
         catch (Throwable ex)
         {
           // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
           System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
           throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
         }
      }

      public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
      {
       return sessionFactory;
      }
   }
```

**Now to create a new user, do:**

```
public class DaoFactory
{
   public void create(Object obj)throws Exception
   {
     Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
     session.beginTransaction();
     session.save(obj);
     session.getTransaction().commit();
   }
}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  try
  {
   User user = new User();
   user.setFirstName("david99world");
   DaoFactory factory = new DaoFactory();
   factory.create(user);
  }
   catch(Exception ex)
  {
   ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Your `hibernate.cfg.xml` should look something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
<property name="connection.username">root</property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>

<!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

<!-- SQL dialect -->
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

<!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

<!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>

<!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">none</property>

<mapping class="com.behaviour.chapter1.User"/>

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Ah, thank you very much :)  Can I just ask, do you have a template hibernate.cfg.xml I can use?  I tried the above but I got errors an im almost 100% sure it's down to the XML file missing a property or two.

Comment: How did you configure Hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've set up your persistence.xml already. If so, you can use the following Java code. You'll have to substitute the "..." with your JDBC setup data and persistence unit.

```
private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT = "...";

final Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<String, String>();
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.driver", "...");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.url", "...");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.user", "...");
properties.put("javax.persistence.jdbc.password", "...");

final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT, properties);
final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

User user = new User();
user.setUserID(0);
user.setFirstName("David");

em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(user);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

HTH

Raku

Comment: Ah, thank you very much, I've not setup persistence.xml; can you give me an example of this?  Also, I'm still not sure what to populate PERSISTANCE_UNIT with?  Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate tutorials

[Hibernate tutorial-1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html)

[Hibernate tutorial -2](http://www.vaannila.com/hibernate/hibernate-tutorial/hibernate-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a Session object to access the persistence unit. These objects are provided by SessionFactory objects.

Check [the Hibernate reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-sessionfactory).